# Define properties in a custom file, for Spring data JPA

Tags: spring-boot

I have a custom properties file for my spring boot application for database configurations. I use spring data JPA for persistence, By default spring boot choose **application.properties** to load the configurations.

How to avoid it and use any custom file, to read the database configuration on application startup

Example : **database-connection.properties**

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://ip:5432/HP
spring.datasource.username=hpadmin
spring.datasource.password=hp@12345
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will avoid future complications if you use just one and the classic application.properties.

Spring requires more than just database configurations so replace the entire application.properties by a simple database-connection.properties is not a good idea.

Anyway, if you need to add more  properties alongside application.properties you could use
one of the following approaches:

#### PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer

You could load extra properties alongside the application.properties or replace it entirely if you delete the application.properties

In your main class:

```
@Configuration
public class PropertiesConfiguration {


    @Bean
    public PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer properties() {
        final PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer ppc = new PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer();
        ppc.setIgnoreResourceNotFound(true);

        final List<Resource> resourceLst = new ArrayList<Resource>();

        resourceLst.add(new ClassPathResource("database-connection.properties"));          

        ppc.setLocations(resourceLst.toArray(new Resource[]{}));

        return ppc;
    }
```

#### Shell

You could replace the entire application.properties file at the moment of run of your jar with spring parameter `--spring.config.location`

java -jar app.jar --spring.config.location=/foo/bar/database-connection.properties

#### PropertySource

Similar to **PropertiesConfiguration** but without java code, just @annotations

```
@PropertySources({@PropertySource(value = "classpath:database-connection.properties")})
public class Application {
```